# Django QuerySet: filter by date, then select one more

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have a set of Model objects, each one tagged with a date and time. I'd like to select all of the items with a date in the past, *plus* the one that's closest to today, but in the future. So far, I've got this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from models import Resource

next = Resource.objects.filter(date__gt=now()).reverse()[0]
archive = Resource.objects.filter(date__lt=now())
```

This seems clunky. I wonder if there's a way to do this that only hits the database once, using one (clean) QuerySet. Is this possible?

Comment: No there will be two queries as both cases contradicts each other.

Comment: By the way, `next` is a poor choice for a variable. It is the name of the built-in [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would not be able to do it with one database call, as there is no way to know what the next `date` would be ahead of time, unless you do some preprocessing.

One way is:

```
next = Resource.objects.filter(date__gt=now()).order_by('date')[:1]
archive = Resource.objects.filter(date__lt=now())
qs = list(chain(archive, next))
```

OR

```
qs = list(archive, next)
```

Another approach involving a quick lookup would be

```
dt = None
now = now()

next = Resource.objects.filter(date__gt=now()).order_by('date')[:1]
if next.exists(): #A quick lookup for the date
    now = next[0].date

archive = Resource.objects.filter(date__lt=now).order_by('date')
```

Comment: The questioner wants to get a single queryset from single query which hits db once.

Comment: @AamirAdnan, Pretty sure there is only one database access (as in what OP wrote) and it's where the `[0]` and `[:1]` are. [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: @MathieuMarques In `list(chain(archive, next))`, `archive` and `next` would evaluate individually, so 2 database calls

Comment: @AamirAdnan Just edited. Can you think of a better approach ?

Comment: @karthikr what i meant is that this can't be done in single database call. And the OP wanted to do it in single. :)

Comment: I was thinking, what happens with `(archive | next)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I spent some time trying to construct a plain SQL query for this and wasn't able to figure it out. I guess that's where the trouble is :) This solution seems like the best way to go about it.